# Jest unable to return value from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jestjs, commonjs

I need jest tests to fail if a jQuery selector returns 0. So if there is a typo, the test should fail.

Here's my index.js:

```
const sample = $('.someClass');
module.exports = sample;
```

This is how my index.test.js file looks like:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
const sample = require('./index');

 test('test for selector', () => {
   expect(sample.length).toBe(1);
 });
```

If I run a console.log(sample.length), it returns 1 on browser console but always 0 on jest. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I managed to go around the problem as follows:

```
const sampleClassName = '.someClass';
const sample = $(sampleClassName); // For later usage
module.exports = sampleClassName;
```

And in the test file:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
const sampleClassName = require('./index');

test('test for selector', () => {
  expect(someClassName).toBe('.someClass');
});
```

So this temporarily solves my problem but it would still be great to know if a better solution exists.